# One sided platform (Box2D/Cocos2D)

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

**I am going to offer a [+50 bounty + Upvote (+10) + Accepted Answer (+15) = +75] for anyone who shows me how to do this!**

Anyway, I am currently using Box2D and Cocos2D in my app. In my case my b2Bodies are following my CCSprites. What I need is code to to make a one sided platform in my game. I know Box2D offers a OneSidedPlatform.h in their TestBed but I looked at it and it makes **NO** sense! It contains things like void (static ....) and then a bunch of other code that isn't very well explained.

**Part1**:
Anyway what I am looking for is a organized method that will create a one-sided platform in my game. My platform is a CCSprite.
**Part2:** Also usu`enter code here`ally when you make a one-sided platform it will just be the top of the object. But I need one more thing, when my object rotates enough, I want my character to be able to land on the side of the platform but I only need that side when it is laudable on *(like obviously it can't be sideways or upside down)*

If someone could really help me and others out there who are facing a similar issue, it really would be helpful to show how to do this properly!

Thanks!

**Edit1**: Are you positive this below code will work with any size platform?

```
if (position.y < m_top + m_radius - 3.0f * b2_linearSlop)
    {
        contact->SetEnabled(false);
    }
```

Also how would I properly implement this one-side platform into my app since the sample code they show only is in a .h file and they don't explain how to implement it?

**Edit2:**

Okay so at this point I up voted your answer! Once we sort out a few things then I will accept it then give you the bounty! :P

**Questions:**

1. With the TestListener code you posted, I will have to do a specific if statement to see if it is my character and platforms colliding correct? And inside that if statement I would do setEnabled -> False right?
2. Will this contact listener act like a normal contact listener if it isn't my character and platforms colliding?

*A few notes*

1. My Platforms are CCSprites that have a b2Body attached to them. In my game loop I make my b2Bodies follow my CCSprites

   1. My main character is also a CCSprite and has a b2Body attached to it.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean with a "one-sided platform" ?

Comment: Sure. Ok so you know in Doodle Jump if the character lands on a platform, it is the top of the platform and not the middle or bottom of the platform right? Thats what I want to do. I also want it to act very similarly like if the character is falling but misses the top of the platform but hits the sides, the character will not land on the platform but keep falling.

Comment: I also included more info in my Edit1

Comment: iBrad Apps, no it won't work for "any size platform" it's a starting point. You'd need to customize it based off of your needs m_top is the top of the platform and m_radius is the size of the character. It's hard to say where 3.0 came from, it's probably just enough to make it look right. b2_linearSlop is a small number that's greater than 0 to avoid problems with rounding.

Comment: iBrad Apps, you should expand on your question in part 2. I've answered it as well as I can given the specifics.

Comment: You don't want someone to tell you how to do this; you want someone to do it for you, and then if it doesn't perfectly integrate into your mystery app, you will come back and want more changes.  I and others could easily tell you how to do the vector math yourself to check your conditions, but you aren't interested in learning.

Comment: Who says I'm not interested in learning :P Isn't that the whole idea of coding in the first place?

Comment: Hey sorry to bring back this old thread but I just wanted to let you know I have learnt a lot more about Cocos2D in the past month or two and I am interested in the vector math because it is a big part of my game. Can you just point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gave the code in OneSidedPlatform.h a look and it it's a little wonky (unused State enum, some bugs etc) but it actually looks pretty straightforward. What they're doing is using the 
pre-solve event to disable the collision between the character and the platform as it's passing upwards.

Here's the relevant function:

```
void PreSolve(b2Contact* contact, const b2Manifold* oldManifold)
{
    Test::PreSolve(contact, oldManifold);

    b2Fixture* fixtureA = contact->GetFixtureA();
    b2Fixture* fixtureB = contact->GetFixtureB();

    if (fixtureA != m_platform && fixtureA != m_character)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (fixtureB != m_character && fixtureB != m_character)
    {
        return;
    }

    b2Vec2 position = m_character->GetBody()->GetPosition();

    if (position.y < m_top + m_radius - 3.0f * b2_linearSlop)
    {
        contact->SetEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

First they're ignoring any collisions that aren't between the character and the platform (I think there's a bug in the second test, since it's checking if B != character twice). Then they get the character's position and check if it's below or within the platform. If it is they disable the contact and prevent the character from bouncing off. Once they're above the platform the collision is processed normally and it will stop their fall.

Hopefully you can see now that it's not anything specific to the shape of the object they're using, it's a bit lower level than that, they're just ignoring that specific collision. So to implement your logic you'd need to first isolate the two object, your character and platform, then check the rotation of your platform and if it meets the criteria then call `contact->SetEnabled(false);`

To integrate the event listener into your code you'll need to define a new listener class. You could separate the declaration into a .h file and put the definition into the .mm. I'm going to be lazy and merge them since it's pretty short:

```
class TestListener : public b2ContactListener
{
public:
    ~TestListener() {}

    void PreSolve(b2Contact* contact, const b2Manifold* oldManifold) {
        const b2Manifold* manifold = contact->GetManifold();

        if (manifold->pointCount == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        b2Fixture* fixtureA = contact->GetFixtureA();
        b2Fixture* fixtureB = contact->GetFixtureB();

        // Here's where you'll need to do you special logic to
        // figure out if this involves your character and
        // platform and if so call:
        contact->SetEnabled(false);
    }
};
```

You'll need a pointer to it:

```
TestListener *listener;
```

After the box2d world is defined you can attach the listener:

```
world = new b2World(gravity, doSleep);

listener = new TestListener();
world->SetContactListener(listener);
```

You'll want to clean up the listener when the world is deleted:

```
delete world;
world = NULL;
delete listener;
listener = NULL;
```

Comment: I will further look into what you said later. But what about Part2 which I explained?

Comment: Also check Edit1 in my original post.

Comment: iBrad Apps, Did you use the cocos2d box2d application template?

Comment: No I am using Cocos2D and Box2D in my app with UIKit as the base template. The problem with the m_top is that the height of my platforms is always changing.

Comment: What do you mean by change? If you're setting it some how you should hold on to the value for comparison, or else you could query the world for its dimensions.

Comment: Ok so I will hold onto that value. So the m_top will be the height of my platform. m_radius will be the height of my main character divided by 2. And what should I change the -3.0f to? And should I keep b2_linearSlop in or delete that? Also how would I implement this into my CCLayer?

Comment: I added some implementation notes. You should post some code showing how your moving platform works. It'd also be helpful to include your player/character. The current code will prevent all collisions, things will just fall through the floor.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5423/discussion-between-drewish-and-ibrad-apps)

Comment: the problem is if I disable the collision, how will I set the gravity to 0 in my CCLayer class? Right now, I am just disabling any collision.

Comment: why do you need to set the gravity to 0? yeah you're disabling any collision because you haven't come up with logic for how to distinguish which collisions. you'll need to look at the relationship between the objects, and as Michael Dorgan pointed out, probably use some vector math if you're rotating the sprites.

Comment: If I don't set the gravity to 0 then my character will fall through the platform!

Comment: Yeah then you've got a but in your collision listener. The idea is to stop calling contact->SetEnabled(false) once your character is through the platform. The collision is what stops them from falling.